# Call stored procedure using LINQ and List as Parameter

Tags: sql, linq, stored-procedures

I am trying to find a way to write a stored procedure that will take a list of nvarchar's as an input parameter. There can be one to finite amount of items in the list.

I also am not sure how to call a stored procedure from C# as a list, I am use to using data types like int or string.

Stored Procedures are being managed by Sql Server 2018

Comment: For such questions has to included information about used database engine and its version.

Comment: I'm using SSMS 2018.

Comment: T-SQL has no list types as such, but there are various approaches, including table-valued parameters and shredding XML, JSON or delimited lists. [An overview](https://www.sommarskog.se/arrays-in-sql.html).